# Is it possible to use 1 GitHub account by 2 developers

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-svn

I am working on a project where another person have joined recently. I am using GitHub as our SCM to do all kind of PUSH, PULL, COMMIT etc activities. Now I want to have another person to work with me on the project, but I can't have a separate account for the other person to do all the GitHub operations. So what I need is, if the other person can use my account to do all the GitHub operations then that will work.

Eventually when that person does any kind of GitHub operation it show my name as author name To achieve that I have created the SSH key on the other persons machine, and **registered that with my GIT account**. But what else needs to be done.

I know it will be best to have a separate GitHub account for the other person, having separate SSH and do separate COMMITS etc. But for some reason I can't afford that now.

Explanation with an example:
2 persons- Marcus and Ryan working on a project. Marco has a GitHub account using which he does all his GitHub operations. Now Ryan also needs to use Marcus account to all GitHub operations, and it will appear Marcus as author.

How can I achieve it.

Comment: Are you talking about a GitHub account? If not, what kind of Git account are you talking about? If you're just using Git on your own system, there shouldn't be any problem setting up separate accounts, perhaps with a "central" repository to which you can both push and pull.

Comment: Yes, GitHub account. The problem is we are on 2 separate machines, we have a central repository. But for now we can't use 2 separate accounts for commit, push, pull etc. So I want to do from a single Git account.

Comment: Bummer for `Marcus` when it comes to Blame time :)

Comment: @StuartLC: Yeah that is absolutely right, but for some reason we have to use this way for now. Means we have to do it from 1 account.

Comment: Then please mention GitHub in the question, not just in the tags, so it's clear what you're asking. *Why* can't you have two separate GitHub accounts? Are these private repositories? There are sites that offer free private Git accounts. You keep saying "for some reason"; that implies that you don't know the reason, which I'm sure isn't the case.

Comment: @Keith: I know the reason man, but I don't want to disclose.

Comment: Why can't you use 2 accounts? One person can host the respiratory from his account and other can clone same repository and push to same. It will maintain commit history properly. If 2nd user does not have push permissions he can fork and clone it and then send pull requests. 2 People can use same account but its very difficult to check blame and commit history. Better to use 2 accounts

Comment: That's going to limit the help we can offer. We don't know whether using a service other than GitHub is an option. (And you should understand the distinction between GitHub, a site that offers hosted Git repositories, and Git, a software system that can be used anywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

- Add ssh keys of both users
- Make both users use the same `user.name` and `user.email`:

  ```
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  git config --global user.email you@your.domain.com
  ```

Well, for the user who has to set not his real name and email, a global setting will be too inconvenient. It will be better to make the setting only in the repository in question. You can do that by running these commands inside the working tree of the repo without the `--global` flag:

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email you@your.domain.com
```

With this setup, GitHub won't be able to tell the difference between the two different users. It will appear as if it's the same person using multiple ssh keys.

If you think you need this to work with private repositories, then you don't need this. The fork of a private repository will be private too.

Comment: I think that if you do 'git config user.name "Other Name"', you will see the commit list with two different names.

Comment: @Avempace yes. For the purpose of the OP, he has to use the same name for both users.

Comment: Thanks janos, This trick worked for me. But unfortunately I have set it globally. I need to set it for the working tree only. So could you pls tell me how can i go to the working tree and set there. For your info I am on a Ubuntu machine and my proj directory is inside home. /home/projects/proj_name

Comment: @sandeep Simply go inside the project directory (`/home/projects/proj_name`) and run the `git config` command example *without* the `--global` flag.

Answer (score 0):

> Now Ryan also needs to use Marcus account to all GitHub operations, and it will appear Marcus as author.

True, as explained in "[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)"

> GitHub uses the email saved in a commit's header to link the commit to a GitHub user

But the *author* remains Ryan, and a `git blame` would still work.

Comment: Or you can push as Linus Torwald ;) http://www.jayhuang.org/blog/pushing-code-to-github-as-linus-torvalds/